# Subtract a year from given date (not current time) in python

Tags: python, file, date

I have a file in which date field in `YYYYMMDD` format. I need to pick that date and product to join with another file by subtracting 12 months to get other information.

**File1**

```
20180131,Apple
20180228,Orange
20180331,Grapes
```

**File2**

```
20170131,Apple,45
20170131,Orange,20
20170228,Orange,35
20170331,Apple,25
```

**Output**

```
20180131,Apple,45
20180228,Orange,35
20180331,Grapes,null
```

How to subtract 12 months or 1 year from given date(yyyymmdd) and get the answer in the same format.

Comment: What part do you not know how to do? How to use the `datetime` library or a third-party library to parse date strings? How to subtract timedeltas from datetime objects? How to represent "1 year" as a timedelta? How to format a datetime object in some particular string format?

Comment: Thank you Abarnert for taking time to reply. I am completely new to Python, my requirement is to convert given date from string format to specific date format and then get a year old date in same format.

Comment: I didn't ask you what your requirement is; I asked you what part of it you don't know how to do.

Comment: @abarnert: You can't represent "1 year" as a `timedelta`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `strptime` from the standard library to parse the date, but unfortunately there is no calendar support in the standard library so you have to use the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library to subtract the year.

```
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
d = datetime.datetime.strptime('20180131', '%Y%m%d').date()
print((d - relativedelta(years=1)).strftime('%Y%m%d'))
```

This will print 20170131.

Note that if the input is e.g. 20160229, this will print out 20150228. I'm not sure exactly what the semantics of `relativedelta` are so be sure to read the docs if this is important to you.

### Why not timedelta?

The `datetime.timedelta` is not appropriate and does not work correctly. A `timedelta` represents a duration in time, or it represents a number of days, but counter-intuitively, a year is not a duration but instead a calendrical concept. A year is either 365 or 366 days, depending on which year.

It becomes pretty obvious that `timedelta` will not work once you find the correct test cases:

```
In [1]: from datetime import date, timedelta

In [2]: date(2018, 1, 1) - timedelta(365)
Out[2]: datetime.date(2017, 1, 1)

In [3]: date(2017, 1, 1) - timedelta(365)
Out[3]: datetime.date(2016, 1, 2)
```

Comment: What do you man "there is no calendar support in the standard library"? What's wrong with `timedelta(years=1)` or `timedelta(months=12)` here?

Comment: @abarnert: Well, the biggest thing wrong `timedelta(years=1)` or `timedelta(months=12)` is that it won't run. The other major problem is that a "year" is not actually a unit of time, and if you try to express a year as an amount of time you're just going to fail.

Comment: What do you mean “it won’t run?” Of course it will. [It’s documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects), and plenty of real-life code uses it. Also, a timedelta is stored as days and seconds, not just seconds, so it’s not just a time interval. For example, it won’t cause any problems with, e.g., DST. It may have a problem with leap years, but your explanation in your answer is wrong, and your comment even more so.

Comment: @abarnert: Is there something I'm missing here? When I read the documentation, I don't see `years` or `months` listed as arguments, and when I run the code I get TypeError: 'years' is an invalid keyword argument for this function.

Comment: @abarnert: The `timedelta` class considers 1 day = 86400 seconds, in other words, it's using `day` as a unit of time rather than a calendrical unit. You can see for yourself: `timedelta(0, 86400) == timedelta(1)`.

Comment: Oops, you’re right about the years param. But meanwhile, the docs explicitly describe it as a duration or difference “between two dates or times”, not “between two timestamps” or the like, and that it stores days separately from seconds. The problem is that it doesn’t store years separately as well, so it can’t handle leap years, but a day is exactly as much a duration—or not, if you prefer—as a year (otherwise days wouldn’t make sense with time zones, or leap seconds, even in general usage, much less in software). So, again, I think your answer is right but explains it wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174900/discussion-between-dietrich-epp-and-abarnert).